# How to make this moving surface a continuous and derivable function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, random, parametric-functions, version-7

I'm having troubles in defining a function of three variables: $t$, $x$, $y$, from a moving bumpy surface that should be derivable relative to its three variables.  Here's the animated surface code, which works very well in the Manipulate box:

```
Clear["Global`*"] 

size = 30;
Z0[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{-1, 1}]
amplitude[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}]
frequency[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{0.25, 0.75}]
phase[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{0, 2Pi}]

(*Collection of random oscillators: *)

oscillators[t_] = Table[{x, y, Z0[x, y] + amplitude[x, y]Sin[frequency[x, y]t + phase[x, y]]}, {x, -size, size, 4}, {y, -size, size, 4}];

(* A bumpy surface fleshing the random oscillators: *)

bumpy[t_, x_, y_] := Interpolation[Flatten[oscillators[t], 1], Method -> "Spline"][x, y]

derivativeT[t_, x_, y_] := D[bumpy[t, x, y], t] (* Doesn't work!*)
derivativeX[t_, x_, y_] := D[bumpy[t, x, y], x] (* Works well! *)
derivativeY[t_, x_, y_] := D[bumpy[t, x, y], y] (* Works well! *)

Manipulate[
  Plot3D[
    Evaluate[bumpy[t, x, y]],
    {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
    PlotPoints -> ControlActive[20, 60],
    PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-3, 3}},
    Axes -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
    AxesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5]],
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
    MeshFunctions -> {(#3&)},
    MeshStyle -> GrayLevel[0.25],
    ImageSize -> 500
 ],
  {t, 0, 40, 0.01, 
  ImageSize -> Large,
  Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}, 
  AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "Slider"}
  }, 
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom,
 FrameMargins -> None, 
 FrameLabel -> {None, None, 
   Style["Some Title Here!", Bold, 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}
   ]
```

Preview of what this code is doing (the animation is very smooth and pretty cool!):
[image]

How can I turn `bumpy[t_, x_, y_]` into a function that could be derivable relative to its time $t$ parameter, and be plotted?

I'm able to plot the derivatives relative to the two other variables, $x$ and $y$:

```
derivativeX[t_, x_, y_] := D[bumpy[t, x, y], x]
derivativeY[t_, x_, y_] := D[bumpy[t, x, y], y]
```

But currently the following doesn't work:

```
derivativeT[t_, x_, y_] := D[bumpy[t, x, y], t]
```

In this case, I get the following error message:

> General::ivar : 0 is not a valid variable.

**Note:**  The solution should work with **Mathematica 7**, since I'm currently stuck with this version for some time, because of an old computer...

This question appears to be similar to this one (without any answers): [How to derive a 3D interpolated surface?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/228986/how-to-derive-a-3d-interpolated-surface)

---

**EDIT:** Here's a simple ListPointPlot3D to show the oscillators that define the "bones" of the bumpy surface:

```
Manipulate[
 ListPointPlot3D[
  Flatten[oscillators[t], 1],
    PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-3, 3}},
    Axes -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
    AxesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5]],
    AxesLabel -> {Style["X",  Bold, 14],Style["Y",  Bold, 14]},
    ImageSize -> 700
  ],
 {t, 0, 40, 0.1, 
    ImageSize -> Large,
    Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}, 
    AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "Slider"}
    }, 
  ControlPlacement -> Bottom,
  FrameMargins -> None, 
  FrameLabel -> {None, None, 
      Style["Filed of random oscillators", Bold, 14, 
    FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}
    ]
```

Comment: `rB[t_, x_, y_] := 
 Interpolation[Flatten[randomPoints[t], 1], Method -> "Spline"][x, y]`?

Comment: @kglr, this is what I tried, but I'm getting a warning message from Mathematica: Interpolation::maple: The Spline method could not be used because the data could not be coerced to machine real numbers.  And the output is then all wrong...

Comment: It works   in version 11.3.0 (windows 10 64b) and version 12.2.0 (wolfram cloud) with no warning message and the picture looks same as the picture from `Evaluate[randomBumps[t][x, y]]`.

Comment: I can confirm using kglrs code in v12 on OSX, it runs smoothly.... and can be plotted...not to say you need to upgrade...but version 12 does have nice features you might want to take advantage of since verison 7....

Comment: @morbo, well, I agree that I'll need to upgrade, but not on the very old machine I work on, until about 8 months.  Currently, I'm stuck with v7.  And I need natural good looking continuous and differentiable random initial data!

Comment: @Cham that's unfortunate...I would give an attempt, but it seems your error is very v7 specific...hopefully someone here still has a copy around to help...Otherwise, maybe try posting on the wolfram forums aswell?

Comment: Maybe try it on the free version of the Wolfram Cloud? That uses version 12.

Answer (score 2):

We need some small modification of the code to plot derivatives

```
size = 30;
Z0[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{-1, 1}];
amplitude[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}];
frequency[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{0.25, 0.75}]; 
phase[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}];
randomPoints[t_] := 
  Table[{x, y, 
    Z0[x, y] + 
     amplitude[x, y] Sin[frequency[x, y] t + phase[x, y]]}, {x, -size,
     size, 4}, {y, -size, size, 4}];
randomPoints1[t_] := 
  Table[{x, y, 
    Z0[x, y] + 
     amplitude[x, y] frequency[x, y] Cos[
       frequency[x, y] t + phase[x, y]]}, {x, -size, size, 
    4}, {y, -size, size, 4}];

randomBumps[t_] := 
 Interpolation[Flatten[randomPoints[t], 1], Method -> "Spline"]
randomBumps1[t_] := 
 Interpolation[Flatten[randomPoints1[t], 1], Method -> "Spline"];
```

Now we can define derivatives as follows

```
derivativeT[t_, x_, z_] := randomBumps1[t][x, z]; 
derivativeX[t_, x_, z_] := D[randomBumps[t][x, z], x];
derivativeY[t_, x_, z_] := D[randomBumps[t][x, z], z];
```

Visualization of `derivativeT[]`

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Evaluate[
   derivativeT[t, x, 
    y]],{x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  PlotPoints -> ControlActive[20, 60], 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-3, 3}}, Axes -> True, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AxesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5]], 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", MeshFunctions -> {(#3 &)}, 
  MeshStyle -> GrayLevel[0.25], ImageSize -> 700], {t, 0, 40, 0.01, 
  ImageSize -> Large, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}, 
  AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "Slider"}}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom, FrameMargins -> None, 
 FrameLabel -> {None, None, 
   Style["Some Title Here!", Bold, 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: **randomPoints[t_] :=** and **randomPoints1[t_] :=** shouldn't have a **:=**.  The motion is continuous in Manipulate only with **=**, instead of **:=**.

Comment: It appears to work, but at the price of telling explicitly the time derivative.  I'll have to study this solution, to see if it works as initial conditions in my code.  I suspect that it will complicate my full code...

Comment: Oh, and in **randomPoints1**, there shouldn't be **Z0[x, y]**, since it's supposed to be the time derivative of **randomPoints**.

Comment: @Cham I don't understand you remarks, since I only seen your code and try to make it working with version 7. Actually the code did smooth picture for derivatives. But it looks like it is not what do you expect?

Comment: The problem with your solution is that it defines another function. Please, see the new formulation of the question.  I need an **unique** function bumpy[t, x, y] to get all three derivatives (relative to variables $t$, $x$, $y$)

Comment: @Cham  How random function could be unique? The only way is to reset random generator by call  `SeedRandom[]`.  In this case we also can remove `Z0[x,y]` from definition  `randomPoints1` accordingly to the physical sense if it is some solution of wave equation.

Comment: I’m not asking that the random values stay the same!  I’m asking only one function to get all derivatives. Also, the Z0 function is necessary, but since it doesn’t depend on time, its time derivative is 0.

Comment: @Cham `Z0` is not a function at all. This is just a random variable (scaled on {-1,1}) of random function `bumpy[t_, x_, y_]` or `bumpy1[t_, x_, y_]`.  But if we reset random  generator with `SeedRandom[]` then we can suppose that there is random variable `Z1` to define `bumpy1` and put `Z1=0`, it is not like you think $\partial _t Z0=0$ since `Z0` is not differentiable.

Comment: Z0 is just a random constant, like the phase constant or the frequency.  Its time derivative is 0, since it doesn't depend on $t$.

Comment: @Cham You are not follow your definition of  `randomBumps`. Just put `amplitude[x_, y_] := 0;
frequency[x_, y_] := 0; phase[x_, y_] := 0 ;` and plot `randomBumps`, `derivativeX`, `derivativeY`. Did you see time dependent waves generated by random variable `Z0`?

Comment: Alex, I don't understand you.  The Z0 is just a random initial position of an oscillator.  It's a constant for a given oscillator.  It doesn't depend on time!  The surface would not move with this.

Comment: Z0 is the vertical position of an oscillator.  Since it's random, it gives static bumps on the surface (if you set all the rest to 0).  The bumpy surface would simply not move at all.  But then, turn ON the other random variables.  It will make the surface move with time in a random way.  If you set Z0 = 0, you would get a similar moving surface, but all oscillators would just oscillate around z = 0.  The surface would be less bumpy!

Comment: In other words (this is physics!): define a single oscillator moving on the vertical $z$ axis.  Its instantaneous position is $z(t) = z_{\text{average}} + A \sin (\omega t + \phi)$.  For simplicity in the code, I called **Z0** the average position $z_{\text{average}}$, which is just a constant.  Now, my bumpy surface is a large collection of random oscillators at different locations in the horizontal plane.  This is very simple to understand.

Comment: @Cham Then your definition of `bumpy[t_, x_, y_]` is wrong since with `Z0[x_, y_] := RandomReal[{-1, 1}]`  this function recalculated for every point `{x, y, t}` we call from `Table[]` or from `Manipulate[]` even for `amplitude[x_, y_] := 0;`. This is why we should call  `SeedRandom[]`  and redefine `bumpy[]` with `Z0=const`.

Comment: I don't understand your argument.  The point is to make Z0 random for all the XY plane.  My test shows it's right.

Comment: @Cham Ok! I will add some update to my code to explain how we should define `bumpy[]` with `SeedRandom[]`.

Comment: I don't need SeedRandom[] !  The random parameters SHOULD change after each run of the full code!